# Java more than one public Enum in one file

Tags: java, enums

In Java, we cannot define more than one public class inside one .java file. But we can define more than one public enum inside a .java file.

As an example this code compiles fine.

```
public class EnumTest {
  public enum Foo {
    F1,F2
  }

  public enum Bar {
    F3,F4
  }
}
```

How is that possible when Java enum type is a special kind of Java class?

Comment: What do you mean by "But we can define more than one public enum inside a .java file"? Can you give an example?

Comment: The "only one public top-level class per file" is basically a compiler-detail, it's not specified by the Java Language Specification. Anyway, most compilers follow it. Indeed, when I try what you suggest with `javac` the compiler yells at me. How do you compile your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example from the question is nothing special for enums. The following compiles nicely.

```
public class MultiplePublicClassesInOneFile {

    public static class StaticClass1 {

    }

    public static class StaticClass2 {

    }

    public class Class1 {

    }

    public class Class2 {

    }

}
```

You can have any number of public nested classes within a class. It makes no difference whether they are enums or not. The rule may often be put informally *You can have only one public class in a file*, but the rule is only for top-level classes. Public nested classes are not limited by the rule.

And since the above works for public nested classes and since an enum is just a class, it of course works for nested enums too.

Public enums inside classes are not uncommon when they are used only or primarily with that class. They are usually declared static. Examples from the standard library include `Character.UnicodeScript`, `Thread.State` and `Locale.Category`.

Answer (score 5):

We can't define more than one `enum` in a single class.

```
public enum Foo {
}

public enum Bar {
}
```

won't compile, of course. Perhaps you're confused by the `enum` **instances** or values.

```
public enum Foo {
    ONE,               // First instance of Foo
    TWO                // Second instance of Foo
}
```

There's just one enum class, but it has two values, both being instances of `Foo`.

Comment: Or OP defines them as nested types like `class Foo{ public enum SomeEnum{..}, public enum OtherEnum{..} }`. In other words they are `public`, but they are not *top level* types.